# Hibernate (JPA) inheritance with One-To-Many

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, single-table-inheritance

I am building a rule engine system and I want to allow users to fetch their requested rules and rules they are subscribed to as notification recipients

I'm struggling to write a query that ***by given a username fetch all rules requested by the username OR he's listed in the notifications***

Since I am kinda new in Hibernate + Spring JPA I have difficulty to decide if this is a case of poor design or just a lack of knowledge in building complex queries

My scheme described below.

**Rule.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rule")
public class Rule implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Column(name = "requester")
    private String requester;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "rule_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Action> actions = new HashSet<>();
    ...
// getter, setters
}
```

**Action.java**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "action_type")
public class Action implements Serializable {
...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private Boolean active;
...
// getter, setters
}
```

**Task**

```
@Entity
public class Task extends Action {
...
    @Column(name = "task_name")
    private String taskName;
...
// getter, setters
}
```

**Alert**

```
@Entity
public class Alert extends Action implements Serializable {
...
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "alert_notification",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "alert_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Notification> notifications = new HashSet<>();
...
// getter, setters
}
```

**Notification**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notification")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Notification implements Serializable {
...
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
// getter, setters
...
}
```

**EmailNotification**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "email_notification")
public class EmailNotification extends Notification {
...
    @Column(
        name = "email",
        nullable = false
    )
    private String email;
...
// getter, setters
}
```

**SlackNotification**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teams_notification")
public class SlackNotification extends Notification {
...
// getter, setters
...
}
```

I tried to run the below JPA query, but it didn't work.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Rule> findAllByLogin(String login) {
        TypedQuery<Rule> query = em.createQuery("select r from Rule r join fetch r.actions a join fetch a.notifications n " +
            "where type(a) = Alert and n.login = '" + login +"' or r.requester = '" + login +"'", Rule.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your design seems ok.
I assume the query error is because there is no relation between action and notification, so the join

```
join fetch a.notifications
```

should be made with the alert entity.
Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881957/cast-entity-inside-a-query) you should use the TREAT instruction:

```
    TypedQuery<Rule> query = em.createQuery("select r from Rule r "
        + "join fetch TREAT (r.actions as Alert) a "
        + "join fetch a.notifications n  " 
        + "where type(a) = Alert and n.login = '" + login +"' or r.requester = '" + login +"'", Rule.class);
```

Comment: When I try your solution I get `org.hibernate.QueryException: **query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list**`

Comment: Fixed: I forgot 'fetch' between join and treat

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by modifying the Inheritance type on class `Action.java` to `SINGLE_TABLE` and using the below query

```
"select r from Rule r left join fetch r.actions action " +
            "left join action.notifications n where r.requester = :name or (type(action) = Alert and n.login = :login)"
```